# How to produce an output file from 2 input files such a way that output file will contain only results after comparing the given two input files

Tags: python, python-3.x

The two input files are given below,

`input1.txt`

```
info="0x101" Data="0x00000000"
info="0x1678a1" Data="0x0a56F001"
info="0x156A17" Data="0x0003F4a1"
info="0x18C550" Data="0x00000000"
info="0x145673" Data="000C60Fa2"
```

`input2.txt`

```
//PS name         above bit      below bit      original            1_info           2_info
//PS_AS_0         PS_00[31]      PS_00[00]      0x00000000          0x156A17[00]     0x156A17[31]  
//PS_PTO_A1       PS_01[31]      PS_01[00]      0x00000003          0x127A53[00]     0x127A53[31]
//PS_PFGD_C       PS_02[31]      PS_02[00]      0x00000000          0x170A23[00]     0x170A23[31]
//PS_RST_D2       PS_03[05]      PS_03[00]      0x00000003          0x1678A1[00]     0x1678A1[05] 
//PS_N_YD_C       PS_03[06]      PS_03[06]      0x00000000          0x1678A1[06]     0x1678A1[06]
//PS_1_FG         PS_03[31]      PS_03[07]      0x000000FF          0x1678A1[07]     0x1678A1[31]
//PS_F_23_ASD     PS_04[07]      PS_03[00]      0x00000000          0x18C550[00]     0x18C550[07]
//PS_A_0_STR      PS_04[15]      PS_04[08]      0x00000FFF          0x18C550[08]     0x18C550[15]
//PS_AD_0         PS_04[31]      PS_04[16]      0x00000000          0x18C550[16]     0x18C550[31]
//PS_P            PS_05[31]      PS_05[00]      0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF  0x186cF0[00]     0x186cF0[31]
```

from this two i need to create another file in this format:
**Expected output**

`out.txt`

```
PS name         above bit      below bit      original            1_info           2_info            new         
PS_AS_0         PS_00[31]      PS_00[00]      0x00000000          0x156A17[00]     0x156A17[31]      0x0003F4a1 
PS_RST_D2       PS_03[05]      PS_03[00]      0x00000003          0x1678A1[00]     0x1678A1[05]      0x0a56F001
PS_N_YD_C       PS_03[06]      PS_03[06]      0x00000000          0x1678A1[06]     0x1678A1[06]      0x0a56F001
PS_1_FG         PS_03[31]      PS_03[07]      0x000000FF          0x1678A1[07]     0x1678A1[31]      0x0a56F001
PS_F_23_ASD     PS_04[07]      PS_03[00]      0x00000000          0x18C550[00]     0x18C550[07]      0x00000000
PS_A_0_STR      PS_04[15]      PS_04[08]      0x00000FFF          0x18C550[08]     0x18C550[15]      0x00000000
PS_AD_0         PS_04[31]      PS_04[16]      0x00000000          0x18C550[16]     0x18C550[31]      0x00000000
```

the **output file** is created in this manner:

read **input2.txt** and check **1_info** value and if the same info value is there in **input1.txt** then write this line in **input2.txt** along with additional column new which will have value of **data** with respect to info of **input1.txt**.

eg:
in `input2.txt` read **1_info** value which is `0x156A17` and then check if this value is there in **info** of input1.txt. here input1.txt have this value `0x156A17` then write to `out.txt` along with data value of input1.txt `0x0003F4a1`.

like this:

```
PS_AS_0         PS_00[31]      PS_00[00]      0x00000000          0x156A17[00]     0x156A17[31]      0x0003F4a1
```

and if the 1_info value of input2.txt is not there in input1.txt then don't write that line to out.txt.
for eg **0x127A53** this 1_info value of input2.txt is not there in info value of input1.txt. then don't write that line to out.txt.

This is current attempt: but it will only generate comparison

```
file_1_content = None
file_2_content = None
with open("input.txt") as file_1:
    file_1_content = [line.strip() for line in file_1.readlines()]
with open("input2.txt") as file_2:
    file_2_content = [line.strip() for line in file_2.readlines()]

file_3_content = []

for line in file_1_content:
    if line not in file_2_content:
        file_3_content.append(line)

for line in file_2_content:
    if line not in file_1_content:
        file_3_content.append(line)

file_3_content = '\n'.join(file_3_content)
with open("out.txt", "w") as file_3:
    file_3.write(file_3_content)
```

how can i get the `out.txt` in **Expected output** format.

Comment: The comparison seems wrong, because you compare two lines instead of info fields.

Comment: Oh okay. But is there a way i can get output in expected format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the output file is created in this manner:
>
> read input2.txt and check 1_info value and if the same info value is
> there in input1.txt then write this line in input2.txt along with
> additional column new which will have value of data with respect to
> info of input1.txt.

Just follow this.

1. Before reading `input2.txt`, you need to construct a set for quick indexing, and a dictionary for obtaining data.

```py
file1_info_set = set()
file1_info_data = {} # info -> data
with open("input1.txt") as file:
    for line in file: # readlines() is unnecessary
        # you can also use regular expression, but it seems unnecessary
        info, data = (e for i, e in enumerate(line.split('"')) if i%2)
        file1_info_set.add(info.lower())
        file1_info_data[info.lower()] = data
```

The set and dictionary you get are,

```py
print(file1_info_set)
# {'0x101', '0x145673', '0x156a17', '0x1678a1', '0x18c550'}
print(file1_info_data)
# {'0x101': '0x00000000', '0x1678a1': '0x0a56F001', '0x156a17': '0x0003F4a1', '0x18c550': '0x00000000', '0x145673': '000C60Fa2'}
```

2. Read each line from `input2.txt` and decide if it should appear in the ouput file. You can write the output file during this process.

```py
with open("input2.txt") as file, open("output.txt", "w") as outfile:
    is_title = True
    for line in file:
        line = line.rstrip().lstrip("/")
        if is_title:
            outfile.write(line+ f" new\n")
            is_title = False
        else:
            info = line.split()[4].split('[')[0].lower() # also, you can use regular expression here
            if info in file1_info_set:
                outfile.write(line + f" {file1_info_data.get(info)}\n")
```

You can adjust the concrete string format by yourself.